# SvelteKit static folder path doesn't work on dynamic routes

Tags: sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit in my `__layout.svelte`.

I've got like:

```
<img src="./logo.svg" alt="logo" />
```

It works fine with "normal" page like about, contact etc, but it doesn't work with dynamic pages like `blog/id`.

How can I fix it?

### UPDATE FIXED IT!

```
<img src="/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
```